# Get all descendants types of base class

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xaf

I have a base class called `BaseEvent` and several descendants classes:

```
public class BaseEvent {
    // the some properties
    // ...
}

[MapInheritance(MapInheritanceType.ParentTable)]
public class Film : BaseEvent {
   // the some properties
   // ...
}
[MapInheritance(MapInheritanceType.ParentTable)]
public class Concert : BaseEvent {
    // the some properties
    // ...
}
```

I have a code which create the `BaseEvent` instance at runtime:

```
BaseEvent event = new BaseEvent();
// assign values for a properties
// ...    
baseEvent.XPObjectType = Database.XPObjectTypes.SingleOrDefault(
    t => t.TypeName == "MyApp.Module.BO.Events.BaseEvent");
```

Now, this event will be shows in `BaseEvent` list view.

I want to do the  following: when a user click `Edit` button then show in list view lookup field with all descendants types. And when user saves record change `ObjectType` to selected value.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

PS. this is asp.net app.

Comment: With what part do you have problem? Creating list with descendant types, getting chosen item from list or updating ObjectType property?

Comment: @Leonid: Feel free to reactivate your ticket in the DevExpress Support Center ticket (http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q395003) if the solution provided there does not meet your needs. We will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that your approach is correct for what you are trying to achieve.  First, I'll answer the question you have asked, and afterwards I'll try to explain how the XAF already provides the functionality you are trying to achieve, namely how to choose which subclass of record to create from the user interface.

In order to create a property which allows the user to choose a `Type` within the application, you can declare a TypeConverter:

```
public class EventClassInfoTypeConverter : LocalizedClassInfoTypeConverter
{
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        List<Type> values = new List<Type>();
        foreach (ITypeInfo info in XafTypesInfo.Instance.PersistentTypes)
        {
            if ((info.IsVisible && info.IsPersistent) && (info.Type != null))
            {
                // select BaseEvent subclasses
                if (info.Type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEvent))) 
                    values.Add(info.Type);
            }
        }
        values.Sort(this);
        values.Insert(0, null);
        return new TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection(values);
    }
}
```

And then your base event class would look like:

```
public class BaseEvent: XPObject
{
    public BaseEvent(Session session)
        : base(session)
    { }

    private Type _EventType;
    [TypeConverter(typeof(EventClassInfoTypeConverter))]
    public Type EventType
    {
        get
        {
            return _EventType;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("EventType", ref _EventType, value);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I suspect this is not the functionality you require.  Modifying the value of the property will NOT change the base type of the record.  That is, you will end up with a record of type `BaseEvent` which has a property `Type` equal to 'Concert' or 'Film'.

XAF already provides a mechanism for selecting the type of record to create.  In your scenario, you will find that the <kbd>New</kbd> button is a dropdown with your different subclasses as options:

[image]

Therefore you do not need to create a 'type' property within your object.  If you need a column to show the type of event in the list view, you can declare a property as follows

```
[PersistentAlias("XPObjectType.Name")]
public string EventType
{
    get
    {
        return base.ClassInfo.ClassType.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need this because I create BaseEvent instance in runtime( I get info from remote system) and I don't know what type should be, therefore, a user must select it manually. Thanks for answer.